# How to add rank and where it should be placed?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I currently have this code

```
SELECT c.customername, c.customeraddress, 
TO_CHAR(SUM(ol.orderedquantity * l.extendedprice),'$999999.99') AS Total_Dollar_Amt 
FROM customer c INNER JOIN orders o
ON c.customerid = o.customerid
INNER JOIN orderline ol
ON ol.orderid = o.orderid
RIGHT JOIN product p
ON p.productid = ol.productid
WHERE c.customerstate = 'NY' AND p.productfinish IN ('Oak','Cherry')
GROUP BY c.customername, c.customeraddress ORDER BY Total_Dollar_Amt DESC;
```

which provides a result along the lines of

```
customername         customeraddress         Total_Dollar_Amt
Company A            1234 Main Street                 $500
Company B            4321 Main Street                 $400
Company C            1111 Apple Street                $500
```

How would I be able to add a rank of the customers by total dollar amount into this code?

Comment: The `JOIN`s do not make sense.  Why are you using `RIGHT JOIN`?  Happily, the `WHERE` clause turns it into an `INNER JOIN`.  Also, define what YOU mean by "rank".

Comment: Depends on what you want to rank, but - generally speaking - you'd add it as one of SELECT columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by rank you mean what `rank()` returns, then you would simply do:

```
SELECT c.customername, c.customeraddress, 
       TO_CHAR(SUM(ol.orderedquantity * l.extendedprice), '$999999.99') AS Total_Dollar_Amt,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(ol.orderedquantity * l.extendedprice) DESC) as ranking
```